# Can't adjust Winform width

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

Whenever I try to increase the form width in the properties box of VS 2008 it just resets my change back to 1300.  It lets me lower the width, but not increase over 1300.  How can I fix this?  I have a datagrid in the form which has a width over 1300.

Comment: Your form cannot be wider than your monitor.

Comment: My monitor is 30 inches, but the resolution is low right now (1280x800 due to driver problems).  Is it the monitor size or the resolution that matters?  It's a

Comment: The resolution.  Windows doesn't even know the physical size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows in Windows cannot be larger than your screen resolution.

In code (eg, in the form's constructor), you can set any width you want, and it will be restricted by the end-user's screen resolution at runtime.

Your form should not need to be so big; consider redesigning your UI and/or using scrollbars.

Comment: The form size choice is not up to me. But that answers my question thanks

Answer (score 3):

you should check the `Form.MaximumSize.Width` property

[Form.MaximumSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize.aspx)

so if you need to increase one of the two or both make sure that MaximumSize is also updated to your new values.

**Edit:** SLaks is correct that you cannot have the form bigger than the monitor anyway...